# spectrum analyzer that shows 'live' input from the microphone

Tags: windows, software-rec, microphone, input, analysis

I have a friend which helps children with speaking disabilities, and she needs some software that shows the amplitude of the sound immediately as the children speak through the microphone.

I have tried Audacity, but it has a delay of about one second.

Any recommendations on such software?

Note that the OS is Microsoft, and the software should preferably be freeware.

Comment: Just amplitude or the whole spectrum?

Comment: Just amplitude.

Comment: If you really want spectrum analysis then there is a trade-off between using a large window for the FFT (which gets precision and wide band at the cost of delay) and responsiveness.

Comment: If latency is an issue you will be better off with a sound device that supports ASIO  - you can get a USB device with a couple of mic inputs for about $150 - if you really want zero (almost) latency between mic and screen this is the only way to go.

Answer (score 15):

#### sndpeek

No idea if this is any use for you - it's Open Source:

http://soundlab.cs.princeton.edu/software/sndpeek/

[image]

sndpeek is just what it sounds (and looks) like:

```
real-time 3D animated display/playback
can use mic-input or wav/aiff/snd/raw/mat file (with playback)
time-domain waveform
FFT magnitude spectrum
3D waterfall plot
lissajous! (interchannel correlation)
rotatable and scalable display
freeze frame! (for didactic purposes)
real-time spectral feature extraction (centroid, rms, flux, rolloff)
available on MacOS X, Linux, and Windows under GPL
part of the sndtools distribution.
```

---

#### SFS/RTSPECT

Just found this too:

http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/resource/sfs/rtspect/

Windows Tool for Real-time Waveforms & Spectra

> RTSPECT is a free program for displaying a real time waveform and spectrum display of an audio signal. With RTSPECT you can monitor the waveform and spectral shape of sounds being played into the computer's microphone or line input ports. RTSPECT can display one or two-channel audio signals.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think this sort of thing was what my friend was looking for.

Comment: Nice find, especially because it's open source.  +1

Comment: Thanks! This is what I'm looking for! On my PC sndpeek runs so fast and smoothly, but SFS/RTSPECT runs slowly and not too sensitive to my music beat.

Answer (score 6):

Just found this one:

http://friture.org/

Testing it now.

Comment: Open Source [with Github repo](https://github.com/tlecomte/friture). check.  Python. Check.  Awesome.

Comment: Simple and pleasant UI. Configurable with multiple useful visualizations. Great software.

Comment: This is the best at 2020

Answer (score 2):

Audacity does allow you to monitor the input from the mic without recording. Don't know if this would reduce/eliminate the delay you experienced, though:
"either select "Monitor Input" from the input meter's pop-up menu, or else just click on the input meter." http://audacity.sourceforge.net/onlinehelp-1.2/toolbar_meter.htm

Answer (score 2):

Here's another free one. Shows a good spectrum with unnoticeable latency. Also has peak level indicators.

http://www.techmind.org/audio/specanaly.html

[image: Free spectrum analyser]

Answer (score 1):

A few other options from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849486/), particularly useful if you need something with few dependencies and easy to modify:

- A [Spectrum Analyzer](https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/browser/Chaco/trunk/examples/advanced/spectrum.py) in one Python script using PyAudio, Chaco, scipy
- A [Spectrum Analyzer](http://www.swharden.com/blog/2013-05-09-realtime-fft-audio-visualization-with-python/) using Python and PyQt
- A [Spectrum Analyzer](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/05/18/qtmultimedia-in-action-a-spectrum-analyser/) demo using Qt

Answer (score 0):

Using the Volume Mixer isn't enough (right-click the speaker icon in the taskbar and select "Volume Mixer")? It will show level meters for all sounds being played through the system, and should include microphones as well.

Comment: Well, it works, but it's a bit small...the children need to see the levels big on the screen so it can motivate them to speak loudly.

Answer (score 0):

There are always delays in software when you do this sort of analysis on a computer. Unless you're using a high-speed driver such as those included with the Creative Audigy or X-Fi cards which are tuned for real-time performance capabilities.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but if the Windows Volume Mixer can show the analysis in real-time, I think other software could do that as well :)   The problem with Audacity is that I need to record for it to show me the analysis, and I guess that takes a bit of time too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a commercial offering that I found in a quick Google search, which offers a 30-day trial download so you can try it for free first to determine if it meets your needs (*you mentioned that there's a preference for freeware, but not that free is a requirement*):

SpectraPLUS - FFT Spectral Analysis System
  http://www.spectraplus.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With " Alchemy - Open Drawing Project http://al.chemy.org/ " you can use your mouse to DRAW the input sound waveform onto a canvas, even curve its shape. It is in vector form and is saved as an image. Speed can be increased by the movement of the wrist.

http://al.chemy.org/

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread looking for a real-time way to display spectra-versus-time, after losing the ability to use Adobe Audition, WHILE recording.  In Audition, you can do a spectral display that has very little delay; as someone else said, if you use high resolution, there will be more delay.  But a "good" program will use overlapping blocks of data so it can update the display very quickly.  There's enough processing power in modern processors to keep up with a thousand frequencies in a fraction of a second of processing time, if the program is well written, and there's no point in more resolution than that if you're displaying on a screen that's "only" about a thousand pixels high.  I'd submit that for stereo, 1k blocks of audio samples is plenty, unless you're expanding a part of the frequency scale as you can do in Audition.  Recording at 44k samples/second, you get a whole new 1k block 44 times a second, and for me, that's plenty fast enough, without even any need for block overlap.  Even 8k blocks would be more than 5 a second without overlap.  Whether the software is written well enough to actually DO that is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

One as a online tool:

[image]

advantage - no need to install anything

https://www.compadre.org/osp/pwa/soundanalyzer/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).